# External JS scripts blocked by hosting company?

Tags: javascript

I developed a WP theme for a client and I have an issue where two external scripts, Google Analytics and a tracking script from an SEO company are not loaded. I had a look at the console and the status is "failed" and the type is "pending".

Is there any chance that the hosting company blocks external scripts from being loaded? All other scripts (Foundation, Modernizr) that are hosted on the server are loaded properly.

Thanks, 
D

Comment: Are you using an ad blocker like ghostery?

Comment: Yeah that could well be possible. Can you load anything else that is not hosted on your domain

Comment: could be a protocol mismatch

Comment: It's almost certainly not the hosting company, though it's not strictly impossible. If it turns out to be the host, you should feel good that you found out ahead of time that they're terrible.

Comment: oh man, I did forget to turn ghostery off! Thanks @Nirk, that means I can go to bed now. haha!

Comment: Run your `.js` file addresses directly in your address bar. If they don't work it has something to do with your browser. It could have something to do with feature detection of the `.js` code and your corresponding feature.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Expanding on my comment above, ad blockers and other extensions like Ghostery block trackers like Google Analytics.  Disable them!

Comment: yeah, that was it. Thanks again for the hint!

Answer (score 0):

Hosting company technically is able to filter output HTML (and `script`s src), but there're numerous workaround for that anyway.

Most probably, you have a typo or somewhat in script URLs.

Answer (score -2):

The company doesn't have any control over what scripts are being loaded inside the browser. If you put a bunch of  tags in the HTML of your site, there is no way that the company can do anything at that point.

Comment: Can you explain why that is? Because I don't agree with you.